# Reset modal data with bootstrap + jQuery

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap, jquery-select2, bootstrap-modal, twitter-bootstrap-2

I have a MVC 5 c# project using Bootstrap `bootstrap-transition.js v2.3.1`, with `bootstrap-modal.js v2.2.0`, jQuery `jQuery JavaScript Library v2.1.3` and finally, select2 `Version: 3.5.2`.

In this project, the I have a modal with the following information:

```
<div class="modal fade" id="@Model.modalId" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="@Model.modalId" aria-hidden="true">
    <div class="modal-dialog" style="overflow-y: auto; max-height: 80vh;">
        <div class="modal-content">
            <div class="modal-header">
                <h4 class="modal-title" id="myModalLabel">@Model.modalTitle</h4>
            </div>
            <div class="modal-body" data-val="@Model.packageId">
                <form class="form-horizontal">
                    <div class="control-group">
                        <label class="control-label">Package Name: </label>
                        <div class="controls">
                            <input type="text" class="form-control" id="package-name" placeholder="@Model.pkgNamePlaceHolder" value="@Model.pkgNameValue">
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="control-group">
                        <label class="control-label">Select the materials:</label>
                        <div class="controls">
                            <input class="select2s" data-edit-values="@Model.materialsString" data-o2f-placeholder="Select Materials..." data-o2f-url="@Url.Action("MaterialsMultiple", "Home")" data-val="false" id="MaterialId" name="MaterialId" multiple="multiple" type="text" />
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </form>
            </div>
            <div class="modal-footer">
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Cancel</button>
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" id="@Model.saveButtonId" data-url="@Model.saveButtonUrl">@Model.saveButtonText</button>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

And in the cshtml, I render the model using these two lines:

```
 ModalPackageInfo createModal = new ModalPackageInfo("createPkgModal", Url.Action("CreatePackage", "Package"), true);
    Html.RenderPartial("_ModalPackagePopup", createModal);
```

When I open the modal for the first time, it is empty, which is good. However if I change one of the fields, close it and re-open it again, the old information is still there. I want to avoid this behaviour, I want to reset the modal's information when it is closed.

To achieve this i tried **every solution in this discussion, but without success**:

- [how to destroy bootstrap modal window completely?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13177426/how-to-destroy-bootstrap-modal-window-completely)

Changing the package name field to empty is easy, I just do `$(#createPkgModal input#package-name).val('')` and it works, however the other field, which uses select2, is not affected by this change.

How can I fix this and reset the modal's data everytime I close it?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15205262/resetting-select2-value-in-dropdown-with-reset-button

Comment: Wow... easier than expected xD if you post that as an answer, I will accept it :D Can't believe I searching in the wrong tree :P

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There may be many ways in which one can reset a modal's data, however, the onse I used was to use jQuery and manually reset every field using `$(#fieldId).val('');`.

In the case of select2, I had to use the selecte's variant for this: `$('#fieldId').select2('data', null);`