# Clear multiple select jquery-select2

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, jquery-select2

I am trying to create a reset button for jquery-select2 multiple select. I have no idea why my solution doesn't work.

Html:

```
<select id="workload-selector" class="js-source-states-2" multiple="multiple" style="width: 100%">             
  <option value="haha">haha</option>
  <option value="haha2">haha2</option>
  <option value="haha3">haha3</option>
</select>

<button id="reset">
Reset
</button>
```

Javascript:

```
$("#workload-selector").select2();
$("#reset").click(function(){
  $("#workload-selector option:selected").removeAttr("selected");
});
```

I made it on jsFiddle:
https://jsfiddle.net/DTcHh/41975/

Comment: possible duplicate https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15205262/resetting-select2-value-in-dropdown-with-reset-button

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can just do:

```
$("#workload-selector").select2('val', '');
```

Also according to the [docs](https://select2.org/programmatic-control/add-select-clear-items) this also works:

```
$("#workload-selector").val("");
$("#workload-selector").trigger("change");
```

Comment: Does not work for multiple select. It makes one empty tag.

Answer (score 18):

The select2 multiple saves value in an array
All you need to do is

```
$("#workload-selector").val([]).change();
```

Comment: This is the only answer that actually works for multi select.

Answer (score 4):

I have done just that, there it goes a sample of my elaboration

```
$("#reset").click(function(){
  $("#workload-selector").val(null).trigger('change');
});
```

Comment: here docs about clearing select2 values, it doesnt matter if multiple or single ... https://select2.org/programmatic-control/add-select-clear-items#clearing-selections

Comment: Nice answers dude, I'm thanks full for you. :)

Answer (score 0):

In the documentation https://select2.org/programmatic-control/add-select-clear-items#clearing-selections saying that I need set **null** value. When select have multiple choices, it gave me a blank selected option. But if set not exist value, it clear normally for me.

For example:
if in options u have:

```
<select id="mySelect2" multiple="multiple">
   <option value="1">1</option>
   <option value="2">2</option>
   <option value="3">3</option>
</select>
```

This normally clear select.

```
$('#mySelect2').val(-100).trigger('change');
```

Answer (score 0):

This works for but single and multi and is according to docs https://select2.org/programmatic-control/add-select-clear-items#clearing-selections

```
$('#mySelect2').val(null).trigger('change');
```