# Reset select2 value and show placeholder

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap, jquery-select2

How do I set the placeholder on value reset by select2. In my example If locations or grade select boxes are clicked and my select2 has a value than the value of select2 should reset and show the default placeholder. This script is resetting the value but won't show the placeholder

```
$("#locations, #grade ").change(function() {
   $('#e6').select2('data', {
     placeholder: "Studiengang wählen",
     id: null,
     text: ''
   });
});

$("#e6").select2({
   placeholder: "Studiengang wählen",
   width: 'resolve',
   id: function(e) {
     return e.subject;
   },
   minimumInputLength: 2,
   ajax: {
     url: "index.php?option=com_unis&task=search.locator&tmpl=component&<?php echo JSession::getFormToken() ?>=1",
     dataType: 'json',
     data: function(term, page) {
       return {
         q: term, // search term
         g: $('#grade option:selected').val(),
         o: $('#locations option:selected').val()
       };
     },
     results: function(data, page) {
       return {
         results: data
       };
     }
   },
   formatResult: subjectFormatResult,
   formatSelection: subjectFormatSelection,
   dropdownCssClass: "bigdrop",
   escapeMarkup: function(m) {
     return m;
   }
});
```

Comment: Just refer to the Documentation instead of using weird suggestions which wont work from this or other SO threads. The suggested approach by Select2 is: `$('#mySelect2').val(null).trigger('change');`. Reference: https://select2.org/programmatic-control/add-select-clear-items. And that works like a charm.

Comment: incase if any one needs full implementation with ajax https://codepen.io/ashgadala/pen/NWOxBze

Answer (score 260, accepted):

You must define the select2 as

```
$("#customers_select").select2({
    placeholder: "Select a customer",
    initSelection: function(element, callback) {                   
    }
});
```

To reset the select2

```
$("#customers_select").select2("val", "");
```

Comment: I tried this with a <select multiple>, but I get the error: Option 'initSelection' is not allowed for Select2 when attached to a <select> element.

Comment: This does not work for me. The placeholder still does not show up.

Comment: $("#customers_select").select2("val", ""); working for me :D

Comment: See @Lego Stormtroopr's answer below, which reflects the new method according to Select2's API. The above method is deprecated.

Comment: As of v4.0.3, it doesn't seem like `.select2("val", "")` works anymore.

Comment: $("#selectId").empty().select2();

Comment: @Danilo it clears all the values from the drop down if you try to search / select another value ,

Comment: $("#customers_select").select2({
    data: " ",
    placeholder: "Select a customer"
});

Comment: $("#customers_select").select2("data", null);

Comment: `$("#customers_select").val('').trigger('change') ;`
I used this and it worked.

Comment: $("#selectId").empty().select2() works for me also - but I still can't reset to placeholder text

Comment: @adamj how can I do it without triggering it.

Answer (score 204):

The accepted answer does not work in my case. I'm trying this, and it's working:

Define select2:

```
$("#customers_select").select2({
    placeholder: "Select a State",
    allowClear: true
});
```

or

```
$("#customers_select").select2({
    placeholder: "Select a State"
});
```

To reset:

```
$("#customers_select").val('').trigger('change')
```

or

```
$("#customers_select").empty().trigger('change')
```

Comment: I found that unless you have the placeholder defined the allowClear does not work

Comment: Neither `$('#your_select_input').val('').trigger('change')` nor `$('#your_select_input').val('');` doesn't work in Firefox

Comment: this works for me, it deletes all data from the select2 I'm using v4.0.3

Comment: $("#customers_select").empty().trigger('change') works for me. :)

Comment: @NorthCat Thanks. I was explicitly appending the values into my select2, so ".val('')" was not working. Then I saw "empty" in your answer and I realized that I need to use "empty" and it worked. Thanks again.

Comment: For some reason . . . only the empty().trigger('change') worked . . .

Comment: '$("#customers_select").empty().trigger('change')' worked for me, thanks!

Comment: this one works pretty well `$("#customers_select").empty().trigger('change')`

Comment: `$("#customers_select").val('').trigger('change')` worked for me. :) Thanks!

Comment: I tried with `.val(null)` and didn't work, but `.empty()` works great! :D

Comment: ```allowClear: true``` worked as expected.

Answer (score 135):

Select2 has changed their API:

> Select2: The `select2("val")` method has been deprecated
>   and will be removed in later Select2 versions. Use $element.val() instead.

The best way to do this now is:

```
$('#your_select_input').val('');
```

**Edit: December 2016** Comments suggest that the below is the updated way to do this:

```
$('#your_select_input').val([]);
```

Comment: This updates the value, but for it to show up correctly, you'll have to trigger a change event.
`$('#your_select_input').val('').trigger('change')`

Comment: This does not work for me. The placeholder still does not show up.

Comment: This works for me with the `change` trigger addition, but also triggers the validation library we're using--for now I'll have to use the deprecated version.

Comment: This does not work correctly, using select2 4.0.2. It will reset the selection and restore the placeholder, but when I choose a new value (post reset), I also see selected an "empty string" option (i.e., a box with only an "x" in it).

Comment: @kounoupis  i am facing same issue. did you find the fix for this?

Comment: $('#your_select_input').val('').trigger('change') works only when placeholder is provided. else  empty string option will be displayed as selected option.

Comment: Neither `$('#your_select_input').val('').trigger('change')` nor `$('#your_select_input').val('');` doesn't work in Firefox

Comment: Shouldn't this be `val([])`?

Comment: @TrueWill maybe - I haven't had a chance to test it. If `val([])` works, feel free to update the answer.

Comment: The $().val([]) worked for me when nothing else would.  This seems to be the current answer.

Comment: The correct way (see the code for the "clear" button: https://select2.github.io/examples.html#programmatic) is to set the value to null and trigger the change event: `$('#your_select_input').val(null).trigger('change');` If you don't want bound `change` listeners to run (i.e. silently change the value) then trigger `change.select2` instead (https://github.com/select2/select2/issues/3620)

Comment: as @amol said,we need to trigger change,if not,the selected options are cleared,but there are seleted in the select input.

Comment: `$('#your_select_input').val([]).trigger('change');` did the job for me

Comment: Late to the party, but for this to work, you need an empty `<option>` first, even if you use `data` argument. (have not tried with `ajax`).

Answer (score 68):

The only thing can work for me is:

```
$('select2element').val(null).trigger("change")
```

I'm using version 4.0.3

**Reference**

[According to Select2 Documentation](https://select2.org/programmatic-control/add-select-clear-items)

Comment: I'm also using v4.0.3 and `$('select2element').val("").trigger("change")` is working fine too.

Comment: Please note that you must also have an empty <option> inside your <select>.  If you are using ajax with select2, this will help - $('#selectFieldId').prepend('<option selected="selected"></option>')

Answer (score 45):

With Select2 version 4.0.9 this works for me:

```
$( "#myselect2" ).val('').trigger('change');
```

Comment: This made my select2 dropdown blank. Worked for me. Thanks.

Comment: Worked for me for version 4.0.13

Answer (score 19):

Select2 uses a specific CSS class, so an easy way to reset it is:

```
$('.select2-container').select2('val', '');
```

And you have the advantage of if you have multiple Select2 at the same form, all them will be reseted with this single command.

Answer (score 18):

I know this is kind of an old question, but this works for the select2 version 4.0

```
 $('#select2-element').val('').trigger('change');
```

or

```
$('#select2-element').val('').trigger('change.select2');
```

if you have change events bound to it

Comment: Excellent solution. I had to add .last() function to target the newly added select2 box. `$('#select2-element').last().val('').trigger('change.select2'); `

Answer (score 17):

Use this :

```
$('.select').val([]).trigger('change');
```

Comment: For me, worked with $('.select2').val([]).trigger('change');

Comment: I've tried all the suggestions above but none worked for me. This is worked perfectly for me. thanks!

Answer (score 15):

**TO REMOVE SELECTED VALUE**

```
$('#employee_id').select2('val','');
```

---

**TO CLEAR OPTION VALUES**

```
$('#employee_id').html('');
```

Comment: fefe is asking for re-setting the placeholder text. So only the first part of this answer is valid.

Comment: Yes that's why i highlight the answers title.

Comment: The first answer indeed it isn't applying anymore from >4.0. But the second option saved me! This is the solution when you want to really clear the select2. Just setting the .val('') to select 2 it isn't enough. You need also to clear the html. Thanks a lot!!!

Comment: any way thanks @ShankaSMS I was looking for solution to reset and rebind the data to select2

Answer (score 9):

This is the correct way:

```
 $("#customers_select").val('').trigger('change');
```

I am using the latest release of Select2.

Answer (score 8):

I tried the above solutions but it didn't work for me.

This is kind of hack, where you do not have to trigger change.

```
$("select").select2('destroy').val("").select2();
```

or

```
$("select").each(function () { //added a each loop here
        $(this).select2('destroy').val("").select2();
});
```

Comment: I modified to something like in my implementation: $("#select").on('change', function () { $(this).val("").select2(); });

Answer (score 8):

Use following to configure select2

```
    $('#selectelementid').select2({
        placeholder: "Please select an agent",
        allowClear: true // This is for clear get the clear button if wanted 
    });
```

And to clear select input programmatically

```
    $("#selectelementid").val("").trigger("change");
    $("#selectelementid").trigger("change");
```

Answer (score 6):

You can clear te selection by

```
$('#object').empty();
```

But it wont turn you back to your placeholder.

So its a half solution

Answer (score 6):

Firstly you must define select2 like this:

```
$('#id').select2({
    placeholder: "Select groups...",
    allowClear: true,
    width: '100%',
})
```

To reset select2, simply you may use the following code block:

```
$("#id > option").removeAttr("selected");
$("#id").trigger("change");
```

Answer (score 5):

For users loading remote data, [this](https://select2.github.io/options.html#can-i-trigger-an-event-other-than-change-to-notify-select2-of-c) will reset the select2 to the placeholder without firing off ajax.  Works with v4.0.3:

```
$("#lstProducts").val("").trigger("change.select2");
```

Comment: Worked for me but my trigger was just 'change'

Comment: This was the only solution that worked for me to reset a Select2 from another Select2 using Ajax data.

Answer (score 5):

So, to reset the form some of you will have a reset button.
Add the following code inside the script tag

```
$('.your_btn_class').click(function(){
    $('#select_field_id').val([]);
    $("#select_field_id").select2({
    placeholder: "this is a placeholder",
    });
});
```

Or just to empty select field without keeping a placeholder:

```
$('.your_btn_class').click(function(){
    $('#select_field_id').val([]);
 });
```

Answer (score 3):

*as of v.4.0.x...*

to clear the values, but *also* restore the placeholder use...

```
.html('<option></option>');  // defaults to placeholder
```

if it's empty, it will select the first option item instead which may not be what you want

```
.html(''); // defaults to whatever item is first
```

frankly...Select2 is such a pain in the butt, it amazes me it hasn't been replaced.

Answer (score 3):

For the place holder

```
$("#stateID").select2({
    placeholder: "Select a State"
});
```

To reset a select 2

```
$('#stateID').val('');
$('#stateID').trigger('change');
```

Hope this helps

Answer (score 3):

From select2 website,

```
$("#mySelect2ControlId").val(null).trigger("change");
```

Answer (score 2):

Following the **recommended** way of doing it. Found in the documentation https://select2.github.io/options.html#my-first-option-is-being-displayed-instead-of-my-placeholder (this seems to be a fairly common issue):

When this happens it usually means that you do not have a blank `<option></option>` as the first option in your `<select>`.

as in:

```
<select>
   <option></option>
   <option value="foo">your option 1</option>
   <option value="bar">your option 2</option>
   <option value="etc">...</option>
</select>
```

Answer (score 2):

I was also having this problem and it stems from `val(null).trigger("change");` throwing a `No select2/compat/inputData` error before the placeholder gets reset. I solved it by catching the error and setting the placeholder directly (along with a width). 
Note: If you have more than one you will need to catch each one.

```
try{
    $("#sel_item_ID").select2().val(null).trigger("change");
}catch(err){
    console.debug(err)
}
try{
    $("#sel_location_ID").select2().val(null).trigger("change");
}catch(err){
    console.debug(err)
}
$('.select2-search__field')[0].placeholder='All Items';
$('.select2-search__field')[1].placeholder='All Locations';
$('.select2-search__field').width(173);
```

I'm running Select2 4.0.3

Comment: It sounds like you have a listener bound to the `change` event. Try triggering `change.select2` - that won't trigger bound listeners (see https://github.com/select2/select2/issues/3620).

Answer (score 2):

I have tried above solutions but none worked with version 4x.

What i want to achieve is: clear all options but don't touch the placeholder. This code works for me.

```
selector.find('option:not(:first)').remove().trigger('change');
```

Comment: If you use selector.find('option:not(:first)').html(''); it should work.

Answer (score 2):

After trying the first 10 solutions here and failing, I found [this](https://github.com/select2/select2/issues/2830) solution to work (see "nilov commented on Apr 7 • edited" comment down the page):

```
(function ($) {
   $.fn.refreshDataSelect2 = function (data) {
       this.select2('data', data);

       // Update options
       var $select = $(this[0]);
       var options = data.map(function(item) {
           return '<option value="' + item.id + '">' + item.text + '</option>';
       });
       $select.html(options.join('')).change();
   };
})(jQuery);
```

The change is then made:

```
var data = [{ id: 1, text: 'some value' }];
$('.js-some-field').refreshDataSelect2(data);
```

(The author originally showed `var $select = $(this[1]);`, which a commenter corrected to `var $select = $(this[0]);`, which I show above.)

Comment: this is the only one that worked for me... years later

Answer (score 2):

Use this code into your js file

```
$('#id').val('1');
$('#id').trigger('change');
```

Answer (score 2):

```
$("#customers_select").val([]).trigger('change')
```

> this will remove values AND most important for me - it also remove an
>   empty x button

Answer (score 2):

This is working snippet for latest select 2 api.

**Reset or Clear select2 input.**

```
$("#selector").val([]).trigger('change');
```

i.e.

```
$( ".reset" ).on('click',function(){
    $(".select2input").val([]).trigger('change');
});
```

Answer (score 2):

### Admin lte 3 with `Select2`.

After a lot of tries this is what worked for me :

Library at the top ( Modify position if it's conflicting with the bootstrap )

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="/template/almasaeed2010/adminlte/plugins/select2/css/select2.min.css" >
<link rel="stylesheet" href="/template/almasaeed2010/adminlte/plugins/select2-bootstrap4-theme/select2-bootstrap4.min.css" >
```

JS scripts ( After `JQuery` and before your `.select2(...` script )

```
<script src="/template/almasaeed2010/adminlte/plugins/select2/js/select2.full.min.js"></script>
```

HTML

```
<select name="mode_de_reglement" id="mode_de_reglement" >
     <option value="cheque">cheque</option>
     <option value="virement">virement</option>
     <option value="carte_bancaire">carte bancaire</option>
</select>
```

Initialization script :

```
$("#mode_de_reglement").select2({
     placeholder : "Mode de réglement"
});
$('#mode_de_reglement').val('');//setting starting value to empty because by default it selects the first value
$('#mode_de_reglement').trigger('change');//change to let the select2 library know you modified the value programmatically
```

Finally whenever the form gets reopened i refresh the select again using :

```
//... onclick="openModalNewRecord()"
$('#mode_de_reglement').val('');
$('#mode_de_reglement').trigger('change');
```

Here is the template i used [AdminLte3](https://adminlte.io/themes/v3/pages/forms/advanced.html)

**Also** note that you can create select2 using

```
$("#mode_de_reglement").select2({
     placeholder : "Mode de réglement" ,
     allowClear : true 
});
```

Allow clear adds an X button to clear selection and show placeholder , but i don't use it unless that field is nullable in the database.

Comment: Note: Don't forget to set `style="width: 100% ;"` or the select 2 will be collapsed !

Answer (score 2):

```js
$(your_id_or_class).select2("data",null);
```

This will actually clear it without adding a new blank option, making the select2 field clearable, or triggering any callbacks from the change. It behaves the most like a true reset of the dropdown.

Comment: Your answer could be improved by adding more information on what the code does and how it helps the OP.

Answer (score 1):

Well whenever I did

```
$('myselectdropdown').select2('val', '').trigger('change');
```

I started getting some kind of lag after some three to four triggers. I suppose there's a memory leak. Its not within my code because if I do remove the this line, my app is lag free.

Since I have allowClear options set to true, I went with

```
$('.select2-selection__clear').trigger('mousedown');
```

This can be followed by a $('myselectdropdown').select2('close'); event trigger on the select2 dom element in case you wanna close the open suggestion drop down.

Answer (score 1):

Using select2 version 3.2 this worked for me:

```
$('#select2').select2("data", "");
```

Didn't need to implement `initSelection`

Comment: This was by far the simplest way for me to do it. The other methods did not work for me.

Answer (score 1):

```
$('myselectdropdown').select2('val', '0')
```

where 0 is your first value of the dropdown

Answer (score 1):

If you want to clear all select2 inputs when closing a modal for instance then you can add a class "select2" and set them all back to their place holders like so.

```
$('#myModal').on('hidden.bs.modal', function (e) {
    $(this)
        .find(".select2").select2({placeholder: "Choose an option"})
        .val('').trigger('change.select2');
});
```

This approach of resetting all at once can be used for forms either. 
The version is which this is working for me is 4.0.10

Answer (score 1):

This solution work for me (Select2 4.0.13)

```
$('#select').on("select2:unselecting", function (e) {
   $(this).val('').trigger('change');
   e.preventDefault();
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Before you clear the value using this `$("#customers_select").select2("val", "");`
Try setting focus to any other control on reset click.

This will show the placeholder again.

Answer (score 0):

The DOM interface, already keeps track of the initial state...

So doing the following is enough:

```
$("#reset").on("click", function () {
    $('#my_select option').prop('selected', function() {
        return this.defaultSelected;
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

One [very] hacky way to do it (I saw it work for version 4.0.3):

```
var selection = $("#DelegateId").data("select2").selection;
var evt = document.createEvent("UIEvents");
selection._handleClear(evt);
selection.trigger("toggle", {});
```

- allowClear must be set to true
- an empty option must exist in the select element

Answer (score 0):

In order to reset the values and the placeholder I just reinitiate the select2 element:

```
$( "#select2element" ).select2({
    placeholder: '---placeholder---',
    allowClear: true,
    minimumResultsForSearch: 5,
    width:'100%'
});
```

Comment: Rebuilding a house to clean a sink is not really a solution.

Comment: Very true, @Felini , but when the control doesn't provide a clean way to reset itself without calling the "change" event, you have to do what you have to do without hacking the control, unfortunately. I have validation listeners running on the change event for the select elements. Triggering the change event validates and show an error message that doesn't need to bee seen on a reset form.

Answer (score 0):

My solution is:

```
$el.off('select2:unselect')
$el.on('select2:unselect', function (event) {
    var $option = $('<option value="" selected></option>');
    var $selected = $(event.target);

    $selected.find('option:selected')
             .remove()
             .end()
             .append($option)
             .trigger('change');
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

I dont know if anyone else experienced this, but once the code hit the trigger('change') my javascript just stopped, never returned form the trigger, and the rest of the function was never executed.

I am not familiar enough with jquerys trigger to say that this is expected on not. I got around it by wrapping it in a setTimeout, ugly but effective.

Answer (score 0):

```html
<label for="RECEIVED_BY" class="control-label"> Received into store By </label>
<label class="pull-right">
  <button
    type="button"
    title="Clear Received into store By"
    class="receive_clear clear-button"
    aria-label="Select2 options"
  >
    x
  </button></label
>
<select type="text" class="clear_receive_info_by">
  <option value="">--Select--</option>
  <option value="value1">value1</option>
  <option value="value2">value2</option>
  <option value="value3">value3</option>
</select>
```

jQuery:

```js
var $clear_receive_info_by = $(".clear_receive_info_by").select2();
$(".receive_clear").on("click", function () {
    $clear_receive_info_by.val(null).trigger("change");
});
```

Answer (score 0):

I've read all the answers and many have been deprecated.

This is how currently you can clear and set the place holder value:

```
// Clear and put a blank select placeholder
$("#MySelect").prop('disabled', false).find("option:gt(0)").remove();
```

Answer (score 0):

this worked for me using select2 version Select2 4.0.5
`$('.classToClear').select2().val('');`

Answer (score 0):

```
$('#select_id').select2('data', null);
```

will reset the select2 and show the placeholder

Answer (score 0):

Ok, so the actual solution (for a common case where you have a "chose item" disabled and selected first item), is very simple, actually:

```
$("select.select2").trigger("reset").trigger("change")
```

Answer (score -2):

I do this for this case:

```
  $('#select').val('');
  $('.select2.select2-container').remove();
  $('.select2').select2();
```

1. I change the select value into empty
2. I remove container for select2
3. Re-call select2