# Set the value of a select2 drop down to empty string

Tags: jquery, jquery-select2

I have converted some of my selects in my website to select2's and I notice that the following code no longer works. Assume I have in my html:

```
<select id = "CountryList" > </select>
```

Then

```
$("#CountryList").select2();

function Func() {
document.getElementById("CountryList").value = "";
}

Func();
```

What is the simplest way to fix this.

Edit: I am trying to set the selected value of the select to the empty string.

Edit 2: For anyone needing this as a function in the future I have added an answer

Comment: are you trying to remove the select option's or reset the option selected to default?

Comment: @H.C. I am trying to set the selected value of the select to the empty string.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17957040/reset-select2-value-and-show-placeholdler see if that helps

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This works:

```
function EmptyValueForSelect2(SelectId) {
$("#"+SelectId).val("").trigger("change");


}

function SetValueForSelect2(SelectId, Value) {
$("#"+SelectId).val(Value).trigger("change");

}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are trying to empty the selection, use: `$("#CountryList").select2("val", "");`

EDIT:
 If you simply want to add a empty string and select it: `$("#CountryList").append('<option value="" selected="selected"></option>')`