# Select 2 empty value in dropdown

Tags: jquery, html, jquery-select2

I want to display option in my dropdown without value, but select 2 prohibits it.

```
<select name="searchcategory[]" multiple="multiple" class="js-example-basic-multiple">
          <option value=''>All Category</option>
</select>
```

my select2 js

```
$(".js-example-basic-multiple").select2({
    placeholder: "Choose category",
});
```

Comment: Just put something like `-1` or zero on it....

Comment: i want to perform it without any value

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Reset select2 value and show placeholder](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17957040/reset-select2-value-and-show-placeholder)

Comment: Any solutions to this problem? i am currently stump on this issue as well

Answer (score 0):

Use selected in the `<option selected>` tag like this:

```
<select name="searchcategory[]" multiple="multiple" class="js-example-basic-multiple">
  <option value='' selected>All Category</option>
</select>
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: sorry no it ruined my style

Answer (score 0):

To reset simply call again select2

```
$(".js-example-basic-multiple").select2("val", "");
```

Reference from: 
[Reset select2 value and show placeholder](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17957040/reset-select2-value-and-show-placeholder)