# Clear Select2 selection onclick

Tags: jquery, jquery-select2

I have two inputs, one with `id="zip"` and one with `id="city"`.

`#city` is a Select2 dropdown.

I'm trying to clear the selected value onclick of `#zip`.

I tried using this;

```
$("#zip").click(function() {
  $("#city").empty;
});
```

and this;

```
$("#zip").click(function() {
  $("#city").select2('data', null);
});
```

But neither seem to work (or a few other variations, I've tried).

I just want to clear the select2 value (I even have a blank value `data-select2-id="2"` which I am open to switch the selection too).

Answer (score 0):

I got it to work using [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35773629/9240845)

```
$("#city").val('').trigger('change')
```

I guess I had to add `trigger('change')`

Result:

```
$("#zip").click(function() {
  $("#city").val('').trigger('change')
});
```