# Replacing select2 options?

Tags: jquery, jquery-select2

All,

I have two select boxes :

- Fruit select
- FruitQuantity select

Depending on what option is selected in Fruit will affect the options of FruitQuantity.

So using select2, I wanted to replace all the options in a select simply by doing this.

```
var options = [];
            $.each(pageData.products[selectedFruit].quantities, function (key, value) {
                options.push({
                    text: value.quantity,
                    id: value.quantity,

                })
            });
            console.log(options.length);
            $quantitySelect.select2( { data : options });
```

The problem is that select2 is just appending the new data on to what exists already. I want it to clean out all the options and add the new ones.

Otherwise my select box is filling up with incorrect options.

I tried this from this question [Clear dropdown using jQuery Select2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13240047/clear-dropdown-using-jquery-select2)

```
$quantitySelect.select2('data', null)
```

This does nothing though, it doesn't clear it.

Help me Obi Wan, you're my only hope.

Comment: can u pls create fiddle (from jsfiddle.net) ... it will help a lot

Comment: What version of select2 are you using? 3.5.x or 4.0.0?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Assuming you work with select2 4.0.0, and the following kind of HTML:

```
<select id="fruits">
    <option value="apple" selected>Apples</option>
    <option value="pear">Pears</option>
</select>
<select id="quantities"></select>
```

You'll need to listen to the `"change"` event on the `"#fruits"` control, and each time it changes, you-'ll need to re-populate your `"#quantities"` dropdown with relevant data.

Here's how it will look like:

```
var initQuantitiesDropdown = function () {
    var options = [];
    var selectedFruit = $("#fruits").val();
    $.each(pageData.products[selectedFruit].quantities, function (key, value) {
        options.push({
            text: value,
            id: key
        });
    })
    $("#quantities").empty().select2({
        data: options
    });
};

$("#fruits").select2().change(initQuantitiesDropdown);
initQuantitiesDropdown();
```

You can see this in action in this [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/tp3vqb1L/)

Comment: If You need to have a placeholder , you need to add an empty option too like below `$("#quantities").empty().append('<option></option>').select2({
        data: options
    });`

Answer (score 6):

First empty the list then re-initialize it again

```
$quantitySelect.empty().select2();
```

https://jsfiddle.net/qum29ken/

Comment: This has no effect on select2 4.0.0

Answer (score 0):

try this `$quantitySelect.val(null).trigger("change");` assuming you have already initialize select2.

reference - https://select2.github.io/examples.html#programmatic