# ListBox items remains after replace by empty array in jQuery

Tags: javascript, c#, jquery, listbox

I have a list box which I want to clear by jQuery without page refresh.

```
<asp:ListBox ID="lbComplaints" runat="server" 
ClientIDMode="Static" SelectionMode="Multiple" 
placeholder="Select Complaints" Style="width: 280px;" AppendDataBoundItems="True">
```

in a button click

```
$('input[type="submit"]').click(function (e) {
        e.preventDefault(); 
    $("#lbComplaints").val([]);    
)};
```

It does not show any error but the items remain in previous selection.

I tried

```
 $("#lbComplaints").empty();
```

but all the data of the Listbox is removed but I do not want to remove options but unselection of previous option in Listbox value so that user can select again. How can I do that?

By the way i used

```
$('#lbComplaints').select2({
        placeholder: 'select a state',
        //tags: "true",
        //allowClear: true,
        theme: "classic"
    });
```

Comment: You are using select2.js.  see the documentation to do the required changeshttps://select2.github.io/examples.html#programmatic-control

Comment: Can any body help me with select2 please .jQuery can not clear because of  select2

Answer (score 0, accepted):

But a similar answer was found in

[link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13240047/clear-dropdown-using-jquery-select2/28086410)

As i am using select2 jQuery cannot clear selected items so using select2 `$('#lbComplaints').select2('data', null);`
this works perfectly

Answer (score 1):

You can try something like this to get it reset:

```
 $("#lbComplaints option:selected").removeAttr("selected");
```

Comment: Can you just inspect the element and give the actual markup rendered on screen.

Comment: `<select size="4" name="ctl00$MainContent$lbComplaints" multiple="multiple" id="lbComplaints" placeholder="Select Complaints" style="width: 280px;" tabindex="-1" class="select2-offscreen">
 <option value="712">10132 -- 10132</option>
 <option value="826">11438 -- 14928</option>
 <option value="667">12345 -- 123</option>
 <option value="776">14447 -- 14447</option>
 <option value="688">14810 -- 14810</option>
</select>'

Comment: Just check the execution order of the script as well.

Comment: **$('#lbComplaints').select2('data', null);** works with me. As i am using plugin select2 does not let me clear the List box So i tried above and it works

Answer (score 1):

Unselect

```
$("#lbComplaints").find("option").attr("selected", false);
```

You are using select2.js. 
Modify your javascript as below

```
var $listX = $('#lbComplaints').select2({
        placeholder: 'select a state',
        //tags: "true",
        //allowClear: true,
        theme: "classic"
    });

    $('input[type="submit"]').click(function (e) {
            e.preventDefault(); 
           $listX.val(null);
    )};
```

see the documentation here
https://select2.github.io/examples.html#programmatic-control

Comment: Empties all the option which can not be seen after second button click

Comment: Now it works.But a similar answer was found in http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13240047/clear-dropdown-using-jquery-select2/28086410 by the way thanks @Manjoor  Correct answer may be  **$('#lbComplaints').select2('data', null);**

Comment: Glad to know you sorted it out.