# How to clear select2 dropdown?

Tags: jquery, jquery-select2

I am working on a requirement that I have to clear a select2 dropdown box after form submission through ajax. I have searched & tried few solutions but didn't work though.

my select2 code is:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
 $("#my_select_id").select2({
      placeholder: "Select One Option",
      allowClear: true,
      initSelection: function(element, callback) { }
 }); 
})
```

Script to clear select2 is:

```
$('#my_select_id').select2("val", "");
```

Could anyone please tell what's wrong in this code, Thanks.

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/a/35968540/4611027

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13240047/clear-dropdown-using-jquery-select2

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Try this: `$('#your_select_input').val('').trigger('change');`

Answer (score 2):

Try the following code instead of val use data it will work

```
$("#my_select_id").select2('data', null)
```

Comment: First, thanks for you reply. I tried that too but didn't work though.

Answer (score 0):

Because nothing of the available options worked for me (even the official example https://select2.org/programmatic-control/add-select-clear-items#clearing-selections)

I finally managed to clear the selections as follows:

```
$('select.select2 option:selected').attr('selected', false).attr('data-select2-id', false);
$('select.select2').val('').trigger('change');
```

Hope it helps

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
var newOption = new Option("", 0, false, false);
$('#your-dropdown').append(newOption).trigger('change');
```

Answer (score 0):

try this `$('#select_id').empty();`

Answer (score 0):

In case [Leo's](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1807570/leo-schoberwalter) answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42951337/4705950) does not helps, please try the below - it worked for me:

```
$('#your_select_input').val([]).trigger('change');
```