# jQuery disable and clear values of a (Select2) field

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-select2

I have a field that works with Select2 called `location`, where a user can enter one or more locations. Then I have a checkbox `noCity` which can be checked by the user if there is no `location`.

**What I try to archieve**: when `noCity` is checked, `location` is disabled, the placeholder removed, and all values cleared.

**What I have archieved**: when `noCity` is checked, `location` is disabled, when unchecked, enabled and when the form is loaded and `noCity` was checked, disabling is done correctly as well.

**My issue:** I cannot seem to remove the values of the field `location`, nor the placeholder. `.attr("placeholder", '', this)` and  `.val('', this)` do not seem to work and other tryouts have failed.

**My code so far:**

```
$('#location').select2({
placeholder: 'Enter a city'
});

$("#noCity").click(function () {
    if (jQuery(this).prop("checked")) {
        jQuery("#location")
            .prop("disabled", this)
            .attr("placeholder", '', this)
            .val('', this)
        ;
    } else {
        jQuery("#location")
            .prop("disabled", false)
            .attr("placeholder", 'Enter the name of the city')
            .val('')
        ;
    }
});

if ($('#noCity').is(':checked')) {
    jQuery('#location')
        .prop('disabled', this)
        .attr('placeholder', '')
        .val('');
}
```

and html:

```
Location: <select id="location" multiple="multiple" style="width: 300px">
<option>New York</option>
<option>Hong Kong</option>
<option>Amsterdam</option>
</select>
<br>
<label>No city:<input id="noCity" type="checkbox"></label>
```

Here is a [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/mz6j2xs0/3/)

**My question:** how can I make sure that when `noCity` is checked, `location` is disabled, the placeholder removed, and all values cleared (while also when `noCity` is unchecked the field `location` is enabled again and the placeholder back)?

Edit: my question is similar to [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13240047/clear-dropdown-using-jquery-select2), however I try to implement this when a checkbox is unchecked (which still not works) and I use Select2 version 4 which works differently.

Comment: You want when noCity is checked, location's value will be empty, right?

Comment: Yes, emty and without a placeholder.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You just add the following code into noCity is checked event. I run test and it's OK :))

```
$("#location").select2().val("0").trigger("change");
```

Comment: Thank you for your suggestion. I did what you said as `if ($('#noCity').is(':checked')) {
$("#location").select2().val("0").trigger("change");`, but nothing really changes. Could you tell me what I do wrong?

Comment: Wait, I got it, it was in the wrong event. It's all working now, thank you!